# Opening a new query window in management studio with prepared "select * from" text

Tags: sql-server, templates, new-operator

I edited SQLFile.SQL as "select * from" in order to have a new template when I create a new query.
but it seems that still I have a blank window....

what's problem ?

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot get it to work, you could try installing [SSMS Tools Pack](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/). It adds lots of functionality to management studio, including [query templates](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/Features.aspx#NQT). I've used in in the past and it was useful.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the file is case sensitive. Should it be SQLFile.sql ? Are you sure you're editing the correct SQLFile.sql?

Comment: Yeah, but some thing must be wrong....
Any way, is there any way for creating a new template file when creating a new query?